# Where is Alex P. Barker?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, story, language, geography

### Overview

You are a special agent with the FBI and have been given the task of finding the number one most wanted criminal of all time. He's been hiding anywhere and everywhere to evade capture for over a decade. He does however, have an issue with leaving behind clues for his potential captors. You are heavily encouraged <s>**NOT**</s> to follow any of these leads. Most of the agents that have followed these leads have either wound up dead, or behind a desk because they got in too deep.

---

### Alex P. Barker

[image: Alex]

- **Aliases**: Alex, Al, Lex, Rex, Parker
- **Height**: 5' 4"
- **Build**: Athletic
- **Hair Color**: Blonde
- **Defining Features**: Scar on right eye, tattoo on left arm.
- **Last Known Location:** Portugal

---

Your first instinct is to head to the place he was last seen. You begin interviewing a few of the locals and can't quite understand what they are saying. You quickly realize that you should have learned the local language prior to beginning your search. Every local you show Alex's picture to says the same thing:

> Esse é o homem que roubou o banco na cidade! Ele não deve ser levado de ânimo leve. Ele geralmente tem um guarda-costas e está fortemente armado. Um amigo meu alegou que ele carrega um lançador de foguetes nas costas! Por último, ouvi dizer que ele estava indo para o nordeste.

After finding a translator you begin following up on this lead. You quickly arrive at the border and begin interviewing more locals. After a while you encounter a local who gives you a handwritten note:

> Usted bebe en el prefijo, donde el agua es rara; generalmente refrescos o whisky encontrados allí. El infijo donde me quieres, simplemente elimina la última letra; solo dame una compañera, haz que mi tiempo allí sea mejor. El sufijo es uno, sin el e; solo agrega uno y verás. Juntos me encontrarás, en un lugar bastante grandioso; no huyas de los toros, solo extiende tu mano.

Wait? Didn't your senior agent tell you not to follow these clues? You little rebel you! As you follow up on the clue, you discover an old shack on the outside of town. It appears as though no one has entered it in years. The locals say it is haunted. You're not scared of ghost though, so you go on in. As you enter the room, you notice that the room is completely empty aside from a pile of papers on the floor and a writing on the wall:

> Welcome to the rabbit hole you dingy agent!

You pick up the papers and begin reviewing their content. One after the other, you begin to feel more and more lost. You can't end up stuck behind a desk for the rest of your career! Suddenly the door slams shut and a voice echoes throughout the room:

> Solve the papers agent! If you don't you'll die in here! After two days the building will weld itself shut, and even if you solve the papers after this point, you won't be able to get out. But hey, on the bright side; if you do solve them, you'll find me!

---

### The Papers

> **1:** Ja jestem prawdą, a jednak kłamstwem, wzniesionym, lecz pozostawionym; znany z mojej wieży, zbudowany z metalu do przetestowania.
>
> **2:** 你穿的前缀，取出s;至于放置，看你的腿。中缀是性别，是你需要的;弄清楚，你确实是聪明的。后缀是关闭的，建立在谎言上;小心甜蜜的代理人，否则你会死。
>
> **3:** Dirigetevi a nord, sotto il Mare del Nord; un paese rinato, dopo cattive azioni.
>
> **4:** Хоёр, тав; Гурав, гурав; Хоёр, тав; Нэг, Найман; Нэг, Хорин гурван ордон
>
> **5:** Deux, un, neuf, onze, un, douze.
>
> **6:** Siehe vier.
>
> **7:** 나는 당신이 그것을 어떻게 멀리 만들었는지 정말로 생각해 본다. 당신은 술집 위의 언어 학자 여야합니다. 이것은 단순하다, 떨어지지 않도록 노력하라. 잘 알려진이 나라에서, 무한한 벽을 위해.
>
> **8:** Посмотрите на восток, для большой башни; названный в честь души, наполненной силой.

---

### Hints

Each language has a puzzle of it's own to help you track Alex down.

**Hint #1**:

> The Riley riddles will point to either major cities or attractions.

**Hint #2**:

> Each riddle when solved in succession will build a path to where Alex is headed.

**Hint #3**:

> @El-Guest has already translated everything. Now where is Alex?

---

### The Question

- Where is Alex P. Barker?

---

This puzzle took a while to create and is quite involved. I hope you all enjoy it, and I wish the best of luck to all of you!

Comment: I hate to be that guy, especially since you’re an amazingly talented artist far beyond my capabilities...but is it possible you’ve crossed your eyes, perhaps?

Comment: @El-Guest Can't tell if that's a joke regarding the language barriers or what? LOL Please elaborate?

Comment: Oh whoops! I meant the scar over Alex’s right eye instead of his left, @PerpetualJ

Comment: Ah! Good catch! I didn't notice that I wrote the wrong thing. I've corrected it lol

Comment: Am I going to get in trouble being an FBI agent operating on foreign soil?

Comment: Your department has worked with Interpol to allow your operation.

Answer (score 6):

Big shoutout to my friend Google Translate for starting me off with some of these. I know the riddles aren’t perfectly translated, but here goes....

So the first clue says

> in Portuguese: “This is the man who stole the bank in town! It should not be taken lightly. He usually has a bodyguard and is heavily armed. A friend of mine claimed that he carries a rocket launcher in the back! Lastly, I heard he was heading northeast.”

Telling us he’s gone

> From Portugal to Spain; the second clue is a Riley in Spanish.

The text is

> You drink in the prefix, where water is rare; Usually soft drinks or whiskey found there. The infix where you want me, just delete the last letter; Just give me a partner, make my time there be better. The suffix is one, without the e; just add one and you'll see. Together you will find me, in a rather grandiose place; do not run away from the bulls, just extend your hand.

Thanks to M Oehm for the solution to this part:

> A place with whisky and soft drinks (BAR); where we want Alex minus the last letter (CELL - L = CEL); one minus the last letter plus the first letter (ONE - E + A = ONA). Hence he is in the northeast of Spain in BARCELONA!

Now...how to get out of this room...

The papers:

1: Ja jestem prawdą, a jednak kłamstwem, wzniesionym, lecz pozostawionym; znany z mojej wieży, zbudowany z metalu do przetestowania.

> In Polish, this translates to **I am the truth, yet a lie, erected, but left; known from my tower, made of metal to test.**

2: 你穿的前缀，取出s;至于放置，看你的腿。中缀是性别，是你需要的;弄清楚，你确实是聪明的。后缀是关闭的，建立在谎言上;小心甜蜜的代理人，否则你会死。

> In Chinese, this translates to **You wear the prefix, take out s; as for placing, look at your legs. The infix is gender, which is what you need; figure out that you are really smart. The suffix is closed and built on the lie; be careful with the sweet agent or you will die.** The prefix could be pant- or short-

3: Dirigetevi a nord, sotto il Mare del Nord; un paese rinato, dopo cattive azioni.

> In Italian: **Head north, under the North Sea; a reborn country, after bad actions.** This might refer to Germany....?

4: Хоёр, тав; Гурав, гурав; Хоёр, тав; Нэг, Найман; Нэг, Хорин гурван ордон

> In Mongolian, apparently: **Two and five; Three and three; Two and five; One, Eight; One, twenty-three castles**

5: Deux, un, neuf, onze, un, douze.

> In French: **Two, one, nine, eleven, one, twelve**. Under the A1Z26 cipher, this keys to BAIKAL.

6: Siehe vier.

> In German: **See Four.** (Maybe a repeat of some kind.)

7: 나는 당신이 그것을 어떻게 멀리 만들었는지 정말로 생각해 본다. 당신은 술집 위의 언어 학자 여야합니다. 이것은 단순하다, 떨어지지 않도록 노력하라. 잘 알려진이 나라에서, 무한한 벽을 위해.

> In Korean: **I really think how you made it away. You must be a linguist on a bar. This is simple, try not to fall. In this well known country, for an infinite wall.** This could be China, because of its Great Wall.

8: Посмотрите на восток, для большой башни; названный в честь души, наполненной силой.

> In Russian: **Look to the east, for the big tower; The name is in honor of a soul full of strength.**

Comment: Looking good so far! The translations aren't exact, but they're close enough to work. Some languages such as Mangolian don't line up with English very well. Originally I was going to write a Riley in Mangolian but once translated back to English it would have been impossible to solve without actually speaking the language. +1 From me!

Comment: Hm. I find the translation thing a bit silly. What's the point of a translated Riley, when we have to solve it in English anyway? (Did you notice how the back-translation of the Spanish part rhymes in English, but how the Spanish text can't even make up its mind whether to call me "tú" or "usted"?) Having said that, I think Barcelona might be a better answer.

Comment: @MOehm It's part of the puzzle; I will break down why in the Making Of once complete. And yes, Barcelona is a better answer there.

Comment: Well done @MOehm, great catch!

Comment: just a thought-  ROT13( pbhyq frr sbhe or p4, gur rkcybfvir? znlor hfr gung gb oynfg bs gur qbbe be fbzrguvat. )